# Symfony Tasks wait for multiple tasks

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous

I'm starting 10 processes asynchronously:

```
$procs = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $proc = new Process('ls -lsa');

    $proc->start();

    $procs[$i] = $proc;
}
```

Now i want to wait asynchronous for every process to finish and print out state informations while waiting:

```
foreach($procs as $proc) {
    $proc->wait(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            // Print out error ...
        } else {
            // Print out state informations ...
        });
    }
}
```

The Problem is at the wait function. It waits for the task to finish and then go on to the next tasks. But i want this to run asynchronous.

How can i do this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As per the Symfony docs the `wait` method is blocking and therefore will wait until that process is finished before continuing.

If you don't want to wait you could refactor your code to use the `run` method:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $process = new Process('ls -lsa');
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        } else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
    });
    $procs[$i] = $proc;
}
```